# How can I tell if my application has been bundled with Mono instead of executed with Mono?

Tags: c#, mono, mkbundle

How do I check whether my application has been started with mono (mono MyProgram.exe) or if it has been bundled with the mono runtime embedded using mkbundle or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IsBundled = (typeof(int).Assembly.Location == "mscorlib.dll");
```